# error WIX0001: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value at MSI Build with Wix v4

Tags: wix4

If i try to build an MSI with Wix v4 RC1 i got:

PS C:\temp> wix build .\Notepad.wxs -o .\Notepad.msi

wix.exe : error WIX0001: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
at System.Nullable`1.get_Value() at WixToolset.Core.Compiler.ParseCustomActionElement(XElement node) in D:\a\wix4\wix4\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\Compiler.cs:line 3514 at WixToolset.Core.Compiler.ParsePackageElement(XElement node) in D:\a\wix4\wix4\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\Compiler_Package.cs:line 244 at WixToolset.Core.Compiler.ParseWixElement(XElement node) in D:\a\wix4\wix4\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\Compiler.cs:line 221 at WixToolset.Core.Compiler.Compile(ICompileContext context) in D:\a\wix4\wix4\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\Compiler.cs:line 131 at WixToolset.Core.CommandLine.BuildCommand.CompilePhase(IDictionary`2 preprocessorVariables, IEnumerable`1 sourceFiles, IReadOnlyCollection`1 includeSearchPaths, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\wix4\wix4\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\CommandLine\BuildCommand.cs:line 191
at WixToolset.Core.CommandLine.BuildCommand.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\wix4\wix4\src\wix\WixToolset.Core\CommandLine\BuildCommand.cs:line 106
at WixToolset.Tools.Program.Run(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IMessageListener listener, String[] args, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\wix4\wix4\src\wix\wix\Program.cs:line 89
at WixToolset.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\wix4\wix4\src\wix\wix\Program.cs:line 43

The WXS File should be fine at all after i converted it with "wix convert" and corrected the problems, but i can share if somebody wants to have a look.

I assume that this is maybe a bug in the RC1 but not sure if anybody of you came across the same error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a bug. Please file a bug with the .wxs source files so we can take a look: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/gethelp/#bugs

Comment: Thanks i created: https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/7139